# How to solve the heap space faced in eclipse ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have tried many solution but it didn't solve my problem. I'm using Window 7 with 4GB

This is my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms2028m
-Xmx4072m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
-XX:MaxPermSize=1536M
```

Comment: What Windows 7? 32bit or 64bit? What Oracle JDK edition you use? 32bit, 64bit and do you at least use Java 7? What the command java -version on your cmd says?

Comment: window 64bit,java version 1.7.0_25-b17

Answer (score 0):

Increase the --launcher.XXMaxPermSize

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M // update here
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 512m // update here
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms2028m
-Xmx4072m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
-XX:MaxPermSize=1536M
```

Comment: But my Heap Size is still remain at its maximum 248MB

Answer (score 0):

if you already tried to change things in your eclipse launch configuration (as I see the settings are quite big) maybe your OS is limiting  virtual memory usage. On Windows7  please:

**Right click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Settings(Performance block) -> Advanced tab -> Change (Virtual Memory Block)**

and modify it according your needs.

I hope it helps to you! For me it helped when eclipse launch configuration was already configured properly.

Comment: my virtual memory block have 4073MB currently, I should change to how many?

Comment: You could try too options: make it double (if you have enough space in your hard drive). Or at the top of the screen choose to automatically manage the size.